# Facing error after running skaffold dev command

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

**skaffold.yaml**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: karan346/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            des: .
```

**Error**

```
parsing skaffold config: error parsing skaffold configuration file: unable to parse config: yaml: unmarshal errors:

line 10: field des not found in type v2alpha3.SyncRule
```

Not able to fix the issue. Everything is setup correctly.

Also, is there any version that is stable and won't give errors in the future?

Comment: You can see that your error is about field `des`. You can check [the documentation](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/filesync/#manual-sync-mode) and see that the field is named `dest`. So once you correct it, it should work. As for `apiVersion` the latest is `skaffold/v2beta26` - see [here](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error you're facing is:

```
line 10: field des not found in type v2alpha3.SyncRule
```

There's no field `des` in these `api` and `kind`.

Based on the [documentation for manual file sync](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/filesync/#manual-sync-mode), field should be named as `dest`. See the example below:

```
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/node-example
      context: node
      sync:
        manual:
          # sync a single file into the `/etc` folder
          - src: '.filebaserc'
            dest: /etc
```

---

Last available `apiVersion` of `skaffold` at the moment of posting the answer is `skaffold/v2beta26`.

It's always can be checked on [skaffold.yaml documentation](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/)